# Azure policy reporting extra resources as non-compliant

Tags: azure

I copied sample from: https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/samples/Network/no-route-table-in-ER-Network/azurepolicy.rules.json and instead tried to create policy which would deny subnets without NSG.

```
{
   "if": {
      "anyOf": [
         {
            "allOf": [
               {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
               },
               {

                     "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].networkSecurityGroup.id",
                     "exists": false

               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "allOf": [
               {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
               },
               {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/networkSecurityGroup.id",
                  "exists": false
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
   }
}
```

Policy works fine and stops creating subnets without assigning NSG and removing NSG from subnet. However, it also reports the virtual network as non-compliant even though virtual network would be fine. How can I make this policy to only report subnets and not the virtual network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by little bit changing the logic:

```
{
  "if": {
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets[*].networkSecurityGroup.id",
              "exists": true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/networkSecurityGroup.id",
              "exists": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}
```